# How do I get cmake4eclipse to actually run CMake?

Tags: cmake, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-cdt

I installed [cmake4eclipse](https://github.com/15knots/cmake4eclipse) today, into my Eclipse CDT 2019.3. It installed all right, and I can see it in the preferences dialog. But... for the life of me, I can't make it / make Eclipse run CMake! How do I make it go?

Answer (score 0):

In order to use the plugin you need to create a project "CMake Driven". Create a new project or import existing code selecting "CMake Driven". The plugin won't be needed anymore starting from eclipse 2020-09.

Comment: But I'm not creating a new project, I'm importing an existing project. Also - that's good news regarding Eclipse 2020-09, but CUDA's Eclipse plugin only supports versions upto 2018-09 :-(

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: Just checked, you can't do it. As I said you need to create a new eclipse project using a new c++ project or you can import file as "existing files as makefile project" and using "cmake driven" option. Not possible in other ways.

Comment: But I'm talking about an _existing_ project, not a _new_ project. I can't create it... or do I have to copy the files into a new project?

Comment: If you use import and then existing code as makefile project, you will create a new eclipse project but files won't be touched, the source folder won't change, you don't need to copy anything